Is it possible to use scarlet solo audio input to use sound from a pc or phone speaker?
I want to record my vocal and karaoke together in scarlet solo audio interface. I want scarlet to record the karaoke sound directly by using input 2 to get sound from pc together with my vocal coming from input 1. People usually use guitar in input 2 but I want to use karaoke sound to use as input instead of guitar. Of course karaoke can be played in background and fed from input 2 but why not do it directly for better sound quality?
